# How do I request an Azure Active Directory Token from a service registered in the B2C AD?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

We are trialing Azure Active Directory B2C and are having a small amount of success with C# implementations. The confusion lies when attempting to use the implicit flow (for a single page js app) mechanism within the 'new azure portal' - there is no apparent support for implicit flow in the old portal.

When using the old portal, the following C# will work:

```
AuthenticationResult ar = ac.AcquireToken("https://mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/MyService",
                            "MyClient-Guid",
                            new Uri("http://any"));
```

And we will successfully receive a token back which can then be used to call the 'MyService' which would have been registered in the 'old azure portal' and given the APP ID of https://mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/MyService

However, the 'Implicit Flow' aspects are only available in the new Azure portal which itself doesn't have the concept of an APP ID URI, only a Name or an application client ID. So how do we use C# to call this new breed of registered application.

We have tried things like this:

```
    AuthenticationResult ar = ac.AcquireToken("https://mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/[clientidguidhere]",
                            "MyClient-Guid",
                            new Uri("http://any"));
```

But we just get confronted with a bad request after attempting to authorize.

Secondly, how do we control which applications can be accessed by applications registered in the new portal, as this concept of application rights and delegations doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: It *could* be this flow described in this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/azure/dn645542.aspx I shall report back if successful.

Comment: It transpires that there is an experimental nuget package which I'm trying out at the moment, although in my case I'm yet to get a token back. The package is Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

Comment: A kind fellow in GitHub has suggested that he sees the same failure getting claims back when 'Email' is included in the returned claims set - excluding this makes the call return a token successfully. Obviously this doesn't solve the problem, but might be a good lead for any MS based people to have a look at.